# Github-Actions - Making OIDC Role to assume IAM Role within Terraform backend Workflow

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, github-actions, amazon-iam, openid-connect

#### **AWS Account Information:**

- Got two AWS Accounts, Account1 and Account2
- OIDC Role (OIDC_ROLE) present in Account 1

  - Authorizes Github Workflow to create resources in Account 1
- IAM Role (BUILDS_ROLE) present in Account 2

  - Authorizes Github workflow to assume the role and create State files and DynamoDB lock in Account 2

#### Github Workflow:

- My github workflow has two roles ( "OIDC_ROLE" & "BUILDS_ROLE" ) as mentioned above.

```
      - name: Configure AWS credentials from Primary AWS account
        uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v1
        with:
          role-to-assume: ${{ env.OIDC_ROLE }}
          aws-region: ${{ env.AWS_DEFAULT_REGION }}
          role-session-name: GitHub-Actions-Builds-OIDC-Terraform

      - name: Setup Terraform Backend on the fly
        working-directory: ${{ env.WORKING_DIR }}
        id: backend
        run: |
          cat > backend.tf << EOF
          terraform {
            backend "s3" {
              bucket         = "${{ env.BUCKET_NAME }}"
              key            = "${{ env.STATE_PREFIX }}/${{ env.AWS_DEFAULT_REGION }}/policies.tfstate"
              role_arn       = "${{ env.BUILDS_ROLE }}"
              region         = "${{ env.AWS_DEFAULT_REGION }}"
              dynamodb_table = "${{ env.DYNAMODB_TABLE }}"
            }
          }
          EOF

      - name: Terraform Init
        working-directory: ${{ env.WORKING_DIR }}
        id: init
        run: |
          git config --global url."https://oauth2:$token@github.com/chargebee/cb-tf-modules.git".insteadOf "ssh://git@github.com/chargebee/cb-tf-modules.git"
          terraform init --reconfigure
        env: 
          token: ${{ secrets.CI_GITHUB_READ_ONLY_TOKEN }}
```

#### Issue:

- The mentioned step, "Configure AWS credentials from Primary AWS account" works as expected
- However the step, "Terraform Init" fails, as my github actions workflow is unable to assume the BUILDS_ROLE.

#### Error:

```
╷
│ Error: error configuring S3 Backend: IAM Role (arn:aws:iam::123427971234:role/builds-terraform-backend-assume-role) cannot be assumed.
│ 
│ There are a number of possible causes of this - the most common are:
│   * The credentials used in order to assume the role are invalid
│   * The credentials do not have appropriate permission to assume the role
│   * The role ARN is not valid
│ 
│ Error: NoCredentialProviders: no valid providers in chain. Deprecated.
│   For verbose messaging see aws.Config.CredentialsChainVerboseErrors
```

#### What I did

- In the Trust policy of the "builds-terraform-backend-assume-role" / BUILDS_ROLE, i've added the  role to trust any incoming connections from Account 1
- My Organization name here is mentioned as sampler-terra and repository is templates.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": [
                    "arn:aws:iam::678927976789:root"
                ]
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
            "Condition": {}
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Federated": "arn:aws:iam::678927976789:oidc-provider/token.actions.githubusercontent.com"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity",
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "token.actions.githubusercontent.com:sub": "repo:sampler-terra/templates:*",
                    "token.actions.githubusercontent.com:aud": "sts.amazonaws.com"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

##### Desired Output:

- For the BUILDS_ROLE IAM to be assumed by Github Actions